# Making a canvas object loop and redraw each loop in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make this script loop a few times, and redraw the ellipse each loop. Right now I have it set to redrawing (and changing it size) when a key is held down. I want to replace the onKeyPress part with a loop so it activates the loop if say Y is below 6.

This is my script as it stands:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

w = Canvas(root, width = 500, height = 500)

w.pack()

X = 0
def onKeyPress(event):
       w.delete("all")
       global X

       X += 10

       w.create_oval(10,400, X , 200)

root.bind('<KeyPress>', onKeyPress)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You want to replace a binding with a loop? Or replace a function with a loop? Those don't make sense. Can you explain in more detail what you're hoping to accomplish?

Comment: I want to replace onKeyPress with a loop

eg. it executes what is inside onKeyPress 100 times or 50 times (a value that I can change and configure)

Comment: Then use a [loop](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) with [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function).

Comment: I loop with range will execute too fast without a delay between redrawings, as with key repreat.  Learn to use the after method.  There are several examples here on SO, including a couple I wrote.

Comment: I learnt the after method and it was what I needed, thanks!